# excluding folder and block other folders

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to block all folders in specific folder 'inc' and exclude two folders in expression

for example i have structure

```
/inc/privateA/...
/inc/privateB/...
/inc/privateC/...
/inc/privateD/...
/inc/publicA/...
/inc/publicB/...
```

my attempts

```
RewriteRule ^inc/!(publicA|publicB)/ / [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead for this:

```
RewriteRule ^inc/(?!(?:publicA|publicB)/) / [R=301,L,NC]
```